# Can't show image in Jade using absolute URL

Tags: pug

I have recently faced an issue where Jade is not showing the image.

I know Jade has been depreciated but I'll appreciate if you can still help.

The variable has the data from the database and contains the Cloudinary image URL.

The Jade code is

```
img#image-preview.inline-block.mb-10(src!= user.avatar, alt='user photo')
```

I can see in the console that localhost is being appended. Anyone can help?

[Error in console. View error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5h5m7.png)

It is like: localhost:3000/users/'https://res.cloudinary....'

It should be 'https://res.....'

Thanks

Comment: Are you adding an extra quote to the URL? It isn't needed..

Comment: Great catch. I found that the mongoose data type for the URL was set to Buffer. I've fixed that to string and now everything is fine. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for posting in panic. The problem is not with Jade.

I found that the in mongoose model, the type was set to Buffer. I've fixed it by setting it to String.

When it was buffer, string which was being set in src attribute was

src = ''https://res.....''

This was causing the issue, double single inverted commas.

After changing the type, it is fine

src = 'https://res.....'

Thanks for your time.